# Angular components gets duplicated on route change

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, router

When I'm changing routes in my Angular project, for example from `home` to `settings` and back to `home`, then all the variables gets duplicated from the page `home` and never destroyed.

I've created a loop in the `home` component that print a timestamp, every time I do the test case above the timer prints more and more infos.

How can I prevent this behaviour?

**interface-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: InterfaceComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'home', component: HomeComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'settings', component: SettingsComponent
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/home',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];
```

Comment: Could we see some code, please?

Comment: yep I've added to the post

Comment: we need more code, please upload the project in stackblitz.

Answer (score 0):

The [Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) says:

> ngOnDestroy(): Cleanup just before Angular destroys the directive or component. Unsubscribe Observables and detach event handlers to avoid memory leaks. See details in Cleaning up on instance destruction in this document.

Therefore, you should "nullify" all class variables in `ngOnDestroy` Life Cycle hook like this:

```
ngOnDestroy() {
    this.yourVariable = null;
}
```

Comment: Yes but if you have hundreds of subscriptions and variable this is not that clean